# Does calculate filter retain the value when one of the parameters removes the filter?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I'm looking at the following DAX:

[image]

1st param is the expression

2nd param is usually the filter, but in this case it means get rid of any filters on Product table

3rd param is a filter that seems to apply the brand filter on the Product table.

So technically 2nd param is taking off filter and 3rd param is reapplying a filter. Does this mean that Brand is remembered even though param 2 clears all filters from the Product table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern and a better alternative to using ALLEXCEPT(). This removes all filters on the Product table and then adds a filter onto Product[Brand]

Comment: Ok so this is equivalent and ALLEXCEPT is a syntactic sugar for the same? Why is this better than ALLEXCEPT?

Comment: It isn't syntactic sugar. The reason it is better is because it works in all scenarios regardless of context and allows your measure to be more versatile and reusable. Full details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGPvGqzQteM&t=729s

Comment: just curious to know whether if the 3rd parameter was a `FILTER(Tbl, expr)` (rather than VALUES), then would the the current filter context apply to the Tbl? Or should I ask this as separate question?

Comment: I think a separate question as I don't quite follow